# React.js - ForEach as a first-class component?

Tags: reactjs

I've heard of react-templates, but I was still wondering it was possible to make a first-class ForEach component.

My end goal is to make something like this more readable:

```
<ul>
  {list.map(function(item, i) {
     return <li>{item}</li>;
   })}
 </ul>

 // instead?
 <ul>
  <ForEach items="{list}">
     <li>{item}</li>
  </ForEach>
 </ul>
```

Here's my first serious attempt by passing props:

```
var ForEach = React.createClass({
   render: function(){
      return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.items.map(function(item, i) {
          return React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
            return React.addons.cloneWithProps(child, {item: item})
         })
        }.bind(this))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
});

var Element = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
    <li>{this.props.children}</li>
    );
  }
});

// usage within some other React.createClass render:
<ForEach items={['foo', 'bar', 'baz']}>
  <Element>{this.props.item}</Element>
</ForEach>
```

The challenge I'm running into is what `this` points to.  By single-stepping with a debugger, I can see that I'm creating cloned elements with `this.props.item` set, but because `{this.props.item}` is evaluated in the context of some other enclosing component's `render` method, `this` isn't the cloned `Element` component - it's `ForEach`'s parent.

`{this.props.item}` *will* work inside `Element.render` but that's not where I want it - I want to be able to hand `Element` some expression that interpolates the current item.

Is this just not possible in React, or is there some way that I could have the `ForEach` component pass down state like current item/index to the nested elements?

**UPDATE** I can get a significant improvement in readability with ES6 arrow functions.  One set of curlies goes away, along with the `return` (and possibly also a `.bind(this)` if you reference `this` inside the loop).

```
<ul>
  {list.map((item, i) =>
    <li>{item}</li>
  )}
</ul>
```

That goes a long way to help with the syntax clunkiness of doing `map` line.

Comment: The only way to share state is to pass it as props or to use a shared store (such as a Flux/Reflux store)

Comment: If you want it more readable, extract the anonymous function passed to map. Your ForEach is going to be limited/inflexible, because it will make assumptions about how data should be passed (in your sample code, it assumes that the item is going to be passed to as children or item prop). `map` is more descriptive and easier to understand. It's just JS, embrace it :)

Comment: @WickyNilliams yes, I could pull out the anonymous function. However,  If that particular function is only going to be used once, I find that the break in flow--constructing components/elements in a different order than they will appear--has exactly the opposite impact on readability.

Comment: Nonsense. To fully understand any code using this, I have to go and read (and identify any assumptions/limitations of) the ForEach component. Any code using map is readable and has known semantics. Even the name "ForEach" is wrong. Take it from someone with a lot of React experience: this is a waste of time.

Comment: To add to what @wickynilliams is saying... The react docs encourage using either map for inline.. Or a for loop outside of the render to render child rows... It's JavaScript and its the standard.. So its not a good idea to try and make a component to do what a JavaScript function is supposed to do

Comment: I hear you, and I sense I'm in the minority here.  Given my history with Java and JSP I'm having a hard time accepting the lack of a JSX wrapper around `list.map`.  JSP just compiled to Java, and yet using Java syntax for loops and conditionals was seen as something to be eliminated rather than embraced.

Comment: @wrschneider could this be because Java does (did?) not support first class functions? In which case having a helper would be useful, otherwise you're stuck writing for loops by hand. `map` hides the details of looping, but captures the essence of what you're trying to do - convert from one array to another :)

Answer (score 3):

My approach would be to have `ForEach` expect a function child that gets called for each item, and simply injects a react element into the render.

It would be used something like this:

```js
render: function() {
  return (
    <ForEach items={['foo', 'bar', 'baz']}>
      {function (item) {
        return (
          <Element>{item}</Element>
        )
      }/*.bind(this)*/} // optionally use this too
    </ForEach>
  )
}
```

This would look better yet if you made use of [ES6 Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
render() {
  return (
    <ForEach items={['foo', 'bar', 'baz']}>
      {(item) => // bind is not needed with arrow functions
        <Element>{item}</Element>
      } 
    </ForEach>
  )
}
```

---

Now, to actually implement `ForEach`:

```js
var ForEach = React.createClass({
   getDefaultProps: function(){
     return {
       element: 'ul',
       elementProps: {}
     };
   },
   render: function(){
      return React.createElement(
        // Wrapper element tag
        this.props.element,

        // Optional props for wrap element
        this.props.elementProps,

        // Children
        this.props.items.map(this.props.children, this)
      );
   }
});
```

Pretty simple! The one caveat I've found is that the `key` prop needs to be set manually by the itterator function (probably using `key={index}`)

Have a look at my [basic example](https://jsfiddle.net/mattsturgeon/8ontg9jc/2/)

Comment: "Pretty simple!" --- the `map`-based solution is simpler though.

Comment: @zerkms This is using an Array map, it just gives the user direct control over the passed function.

Comment: I see that it uses `map`. My point was that the very initial solution was shorter and more readable and much more flexible and with literally zero dependencies (now we depend on `ForEach` component) and without extra overhead to render another component.

Comment: The actual question asks "I was still wondering it was possible to make a first-class ForEach component." This is what I've attempted to solve for the asker. I am still working on improvements however.

Comment: Yep, I understand that. I didn't mean that your answer is bad, I just wanted to point that the solution as OP wants it more bloated and inflexible.

Comment: Yes that is a fair point. Abstraction (almost?) always reduces flexibility, but it can often improve east of use - at least for it's intended purpose. You are correct that **whoever plans on using this should consider whether the gain is worth the cost.** My apologies if I have sounded at all hostile or defensive.

Comment: what I would recommend @MattSturgeon is you make your component more flexible with a type of element to render and such... that way it can be dynamic, whether you want to make rows with `<ul>` or `<table>` or `<div>` s... to me that would be a sufficient answer.. currently its limited to one element type which is not that great of an answer IMO :)

Comment: Good shout @JohnRuddell, I'd been trying to decide the best way to do that - the code now reflects.

Comment: This is a slight improvement -- you still have the syntax bloat of needing to wrap the children of `ForEach`  with an anonymous function, but at least the `map` goes away.

Comment: To anyone reading this, **please don't use it**. By the time you've fully implemented a component like this, you have *a informally-specified, bug-ridden implementation of `map`*! `<ForEach items={items}>{someFunction}</ForEach>` is no simpler than `items.map(someFunction)`!!