# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined in javascript / React-router / React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can anybody please help with this error in java script. I am using React router to display various components of the pages. Among those one of the components is 'forEach'. The console is giving issue with "forEach" property. What is the problem ? Have included this js file into the main html file.

```
var ProductTable = React.createClass({
          render: function() {
            var rows = [];
            var lastCategory = null;
            this.props.products.forEach(function(product) {
              if (product.name.indexOf(this.props.filterText) === -1 || (!product.stocked && this.props.inStockOnly)) {
                return ;
              }
              if (product.category !== lastCategory) {
                rows.push(React.createElement(ProductCategoryRow, { category: product.category, key: product.category }));
              }
                rows.push(React.createElement(ProductRow, { product: product, key: product.name }));
                lastCategory = product.category;
            }.bind(this));
            return (
                    React.createElement("table",null,
                        React.createElement("thead",null,
                                React.createElement("tr",null,
                                        React.createElement("th",null,"Name"),
                                        React.createElement("th",null,"Price")
                                    )
                            ),
                            React.createElement("tbody",null,rows)
                    )
            )
          }
        });
```

Comment: Don't you need to create the ForEach element with `createClass`? Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33681136/react-js-foreach-as-a-first-class-component

Comment: It's telling you `this.props.products` is `undefined` thus it has no `forEach` method. Make sure it is getting populated before `render()` is called

Comment: what is the actual error being thrown?

Comment: Thanks @Patrik Evans, you are right. I just checked the console. Value coming is empty, thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use defaultProps to handle this and also make sure your parent component is passing products as an array

```
getDefaultProps: function() {
  return products: []
}
```